# javascript sync ajax call issue

Tags: javascript

i ma trying to fetch list of names  of htmls from ajax call and then for each html another ajax call and then i am trying to append it using handlebar. but this is not happening with below code. can somebody help me in debugging it :

```
$.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/' + pageName.page, function (data) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, rec) {
        promises.push($.get('commonCore/templates/' + rec.templateHtml));
    });
    $.when.apply(this, promises).then(function() { //after all requests complete
        $.each(arguments, function(i, html) {
            var filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(html);
            replaceFilterTemplate(filterTemplate,data[i].classids);// this functions appends html to div -data[i].classids
        })
    })
});
```

after each html is fetched it should be appended and then next call should happen

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` returns the jqXHR Object. That's what you're actually adding to your `promises` array.

You should use synchrone calls, or reformat your code to handle all the fetches async and then proceed through the promises.

Synchrone alternative:

```
$.each(data, function (i, rec) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'commonCore/templates/' + rec.templateHtml, 
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
             promises.push(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @sammy should i use toString for this